# Уведомления в Android в заданное время

Tags: java, android, уведомления, android-notification, android-alarm-manager

Пользователь создает себе задачи и выставляет время, когда ему напомнить о них. (Например: Напомнить за 15 минут, час, день и т.д.).

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Интересует ваше мнение. Что выбрать? Service? Тогда как ему задать, чтобы Notification появлялись именно в определенное время?

Comment: Вопрос не имеет отношения к `Push Notifications`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для выбора реализации можно воспользоваться этой диаграммой
[image: Полная статья здесь https://plus.google.com/photos/photo/108967384991768947849/6192956249638257586]

Answer (score 3):

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Там настолько свободный полет, что только вам будет правильно реализовывать процесс. И куча примеров, как написано выше [Поиск в Google](https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl)